# How to show all inherited data members on the same level in LLDB

Tags: lldb

I have been fiddling around with the following for some time but have not been able to find a simple solution anywhere.

Let's say I have the following:

```
> frame variable map[1] -T -D1 -P1
(QMapNode<QByteArray, int>) [1] = {
  (QMapNodeBase) QMapNodeBase ={...}
  (QByteArray) key = "this is a key"{...}
  (int) value = 44
}
```

But instead of `(QMapNodeBase) QMapNodeBase ={...}` I would like to directly see all members of the superclass QMapNodeBase (and its superclasses as far as present), like this:

```
> frame variable map[1] -T -D1 -P1
(QMapNode<QByteArray, int>) [1] = {
  (quintptr) p = 6144384
  (QMapNodeBase *) left = 0x0000000000000000{...}
  (QMapNodeBase *) right = 0x0000000000000000{...}
  (QByteArray) key = "this is a key"{...}
  (int) value = 44
}
```

The -F option is not suitable for different reasons; neither -D2 seems to be suitable, because it adds a nesting level, and I would have to increase -Dn (n>2) for each inheritance level.

Does anyone know a simple way how to do this?

Here is a complete working example which demonstrates the problem (see the comments for more information):

```
struct Top
{
    int t;
    Top():t(123) {}
};

struct Middle : public Top
{
    int m;
    Middle():m(456){}
};

struct Bottom : public Middle
{
    int b;
    Bottom():b(789){}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Bottom bottom;
    return 0;
}

/* Run this in LLDB with a breakpoint at statement "return 0;"

(lldb) frame variable bottom
>(Bottom) bottom = {
>  Middle = {
>    Top = (t = 123)
>    m = 456
>  }
>  b = 789
>}

I have this:
>(lldb) frame variable bottom -T -D1 -P1
>(Bottom) bottom = {
>  (Middle) Middle ={...}
>  (int) b = 789
>}

I want something like this instead:
>(lldb) frame variable bottom -T -D1 -P1
>(Bottom) bottom = {
>  (int) t = 123
>  (int) m = 456
>  (int) b = 789
>}
*/
```

Comment: lldb doesn't have an option to flatten all the nested subclasses because the names are not guaranteed to be unique, so we need a way and to distinguish `Base::foo` from `DerivedFromBase::foo`.  `-F` is a nice compromise that discloses all the children, but keeps them distinct.  
However, you can certainly write a synthetic child provider that recurses through all the base classes of its SBValue and presents all their ivars as direct children of the value.

Comment: See:
 
https://lldb.llvm.org/use/variable.html#synthetic-children

and:

https://lldb.llvm.org/python_api/lldb.SBValue.html#lldb.SBValue

for more details.

Comment: > so we need a way and to distinguish Base::foo from DerivedFromBase::foo   \n\n That's not difficult, just prefix with the class name as it is actually done today already, just by enclosing the members with classname {} instead of e.g. classname.membername for each.

Comment: > See: lldb.llvm.org/use/variable.html#synthetic-children \n\n I'm a bit confused that I have to use a rather complex implementation, even dependend on yet another technology (Python) to solve such a trivial problem. I still cannot believe that there is a simpler solution.